# Changing watchdog timeout on RPi3

Tags: pi-3, watchdog

I want to change the timeout value of RPi (I use RPi3) internal watchdog.

I wrote the simple application like so:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/watchdog.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  int timeout = 25;
  int fd;
  fd = open("/dev/watchdog", O_WRONLY);
  if (-1 == fd)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to opeln file " << argv[1] << ". Errno: " << std::endl;
    perror("ERROR MSG: ");
    return 4;
  }

  int retIoctl = ioctl(fd, WDIOC_SETTIMEOUT, &timeout);

  std::cout << "Ioctl returned: " << retIoctl << " and errno: " << std::endl;
  perror("ERROR MSG: ");

  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work on RPi and I get the message:

```
Ioctl returned: -1 and errno: 
ERROR MSG: : Bad file descriptor
```

I have tested this with `/dev/watchdog` and `/dev/watchdog0`, but I think that there is no difference between them.

I use `bcm2835_wdt` kernel module to enable watchdog.

**Question:**
What is the correct way to change the watchdog timeout value?

Is RPi watchdog configuration handled somehow differently that a typical linux watchdog?

**EDIT:**
Updated the code.

I'm running my application as root and I do it in initramfs where I don't have systemd.

I have also found a blog entry that claims that [bcm2835 watchdog can only have timeout value equal to 15 seconds](https://iflorian.com/watchdog-cannot-set-timeout-16-errno-22-invalid-argument/).

I have tested it and it is partially true: I was unable to set timeout bigger than 15 sec.

Does anybody can explain why is that and point to some bcm2835 documentation?

Comment: You didnt check the return code of `open()`. It presumably failed. Did you run as root? If using systemd see the `wdctl` command.

Comment: It did fail on open when I tried it as non-root user, but later I have tried as root and open worked (I have changed a code a bit) and I got the message that ioctl returned `-1` and perror gave the output: `Invalid argument`, but which argument? Somehow it works on my PC but not on RPi...

Comment: You are right. The bcm watchdog is limited to 15 seconds. The latest kernel [driver](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/watchdog/bcm2835_wdt.c) shows the register mask  `PM_WDOG_TIME_SET` is 20 bits, and  `WDOG_TICKS_TO_SECS` involves shifting by 16 bits which leaves only 4 bits to hold the time in seconds.

Comment: Ok. This sucks, but thank you anyway for info and link to the driver.